# I m trying to post video on user timeline but it showing (#100) No permission to publish video

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am working on a project where I need to upload a video to a user's Facebook timeline using the Facebook Graph API. I've implemented the following code, but I'm encountering an issue:

`< !DOCTYPE html>

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script async crossorigin="anonymous"
        src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v10.0&appId=1412620236302264"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="loginAndUpload()">Upload Video to Facebook</button>
    <script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '1***26202****2264',
                autoLogAppEvents: true,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v3.3',
                auth: {
                    scope: 'publish_video'
                }
            });
        })
        function loginAndUpload() {

            FB.login(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    uploadVideo(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                } else {
                    console.log('User canceled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            }, {
                scope: 'publish_video'
            });
        }

        function uploadVideo(accessToken) {
            // accessToken = 'EAAUExUdjJ7gBO8zyvpG9PjuWVBcFXNnYeqK8BK4cmZARaiCMBjNGB8B8IH0T78ygpXUvD...q';
            console.log(accessToken);
            var videoUrl = 'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/paradisemedia/videos/hgTruZDuJ2uO7sP0SAkEr4iPXCpr56DVExBHyIxs.mp4';
            FB.api(
                '/me/videos',
                'post',
                {
                    source: videoUrl,
                    access_token: accessToken,
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        console.log('Error uploading video:', response.error);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Video uploaded successfully. Video ID:', response.id);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>`
```

'The error I'm encountering is: (#100) No permission to publish video.
I have already requested the publish_video permission when initializing the Facebook SDK. Can someone please guide me on what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?'

Comment: You can not request a permission via FB.init, that whole `auth` object in the parameters there, makes no sense to begin with. You need to ask for permissions during login - which you apparently attempted, but it doesn't look like that actually worked. When you log your access token value and put it through the FB access token debugger - what permissions does it actually show?